# Batch file command for giving conditionally different responses

Tags: batch-file

I recently started to make a batch file game, but I've gotten stuck. I made a lot of options for the player and I want them to go to different endings depending on their choice. Here's an example what I've done:

First you're given 3 sentences and have to choose one:

```
:casual
cls
echo Hi
echo 1- I found your contact from your blog. 
echo 2- It's %name%'s mail address, am I correct ? ._.
echo 3- I'm %name2%, I would like to meet you.
echo.
echo And now?
set /p answer=
if %answer%==1 goto m1
if %answer%==2 goto m2
if %answer%==3 goto m3
```

Then you choose one and proceed to another and finally you end up at:

```
:mm1
cls
echo I found your contact from your blog. How is it going? How do you spend your days in quarantine?
echo Send? Y/N
set /p a=
if %a%==n goto ff
if %a%==y goto firstmail
```

But there are a lot of different combinations and I don't want to send everyone to the same answer. And I don't directly change the story for everyone but for some time I send all of them to the same page.

After some time, the story continues and there will be a mail coming from the other person and at that point I want player to proceed from where they left, show the previous option they chose.

I tried to give `%a%` for the first option, then `%b% %c%`, and when you finally come to the point where it should change for everyone. I tried something like this:

```
    :mail2
 cls
 echo.
 echo You have a mail from strandedseagul@mail.de 
 pause 
 if %a%==y goto t1
 if %b%==y goto t2
```

and so on...

But of course it doesn't work because they are different. How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

I just had to set final answer without `/p`; I didn't know what it stands for so I was always using it.

Comment: Nice. It is good that you answered your own question. But the code in the question could have been a bit shorter (minimal example). I don't complain about the question size in this particular case, but creating a minimal example that reproduces a problem before asking the community often helps one to find the answer even before asking :-)

Comment: `set "var=value"` sets a variable. `set /p "var=string" asks the user for input with `string` as prompt. Bookmark [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt) as reference.

Comment: `Choice /C 123 /M "And now"` will prompt with `And now [1,2,3]?` and will only allow the input of `1`, `2`, or `3`. `Choice /M "Send"` will prompt with `Send [Y,N]?` and will only allow the case insensitive, _(can be made case sensitive too with `/CS` option)_, input `Y` or `N`. The end user responses will be returned as useable errorlevels, the first item returning an errorlevel of `1`, the next of `2` etc.. Please open a Command Prompt window, type `choice /?`, press the 'Enter' key and read its usage information. It will considerably improve your code.

Comment: Glad to see you found the answer on your own! I would definitely recommend looking up what a command does before using it, though ;-)

Comment: Thanks for correcting) Yes I rushed a bit about it, but making this mistake encouraged me to learn the fundamentals first.